# PrimeNG pResizableColumn Directive

Tags: angular, primeng-turbotable

Using PrimeNG 5.2.5 there seems to be an issue with resizable columns.  If I want the ability to toggle the feature on and off you can't because of the pResizableColumn directive that is added to the template.  Even if you set the p-table [resizableColumns]="false" the resize handles still show up because of the pResizableColumn directive.  Is there a way to toggle a directive attribute in Angular 5 easily?

basically I want this:

```
<ng-template>
  <tr>
   <th pResizableColumn> ...
```

to be:

```
<ng-template>
  <tr>
   <th> ...
```

by toggling a variable? Is there a good way to do this without repeating the  block and adding an *ngIf to it?

Answer (score 5):

looks like there is an input to disable it. If you use:

```
[pResizableColumnDisabled]="true"
```

it will disable the column resizing.

Comment: sorry dump question. Where exactly do I put the line [pResizableColumnDisabled]="true"?

Comment: ok just realized I need to add the directive itself as well like 
<th pResizableColumn [pResizableColumnDisabled]="true">